# http handlers and modules: what's a good example of a problem they solve?

Tags: asp.net

I got this in an interview question -- the question was more about what they do, which I didn't know beyond very vague terms. But after reading about them I'm still no closer to an understanding of **what problems I would solve with an HttpHandler or HttpModule**. I've worked a fair amount in ASP.NET but it's been a few years -- is this a large gap in my knowledge? Something that's been replaced by more current technology?

Clarification: what's a common problem in the ASP.NET world that would be much easier to solve with an HttpHandler as opposed to something you'd do in a webservice or an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not ASP.NET is built using HTTP handlers and HTTP modules to provide default ASP.NET behavior. For a good write-up, please see [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx):

> An ASP.NET HTTP handler is the process
>   (frequently referred to as the
>   "endpoint") that runs in response to a
>   request made to an ASP.NET Web
>   application. The most common handler
>   is an ASP.NET page handler that
>   processes .aspx files. When users
>   request an .aspx file, the request is
>   processed by the page through the page
>   handler. You can create your own HTTP
>   handlers that render custom output to
>   the browser.
>
> An HTTP module is an assembly that is
>   called on every request that is made
>   to your application. HTTP modules are
>   called as part of the ASP.NET request
>   pipeline and have access to life-cycle
>   events throughout the request. HTTP
>   modules let you examine incoming and
>   outgoing requests and take action
>   based on the request.

Comment: Well, I was aware that they were down there in the guts of ASP.NET. But still leaves me wondering what I would do with such an animal that I couldn't do with say a webservice or ajax. Since it was an interview question it made me think maybe there was some use for these things that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Apologies, I see there are sample uses on that page.